# SSRS remove #ERROR from working days expression results

Tags: reporting-services

Im a bit stumped at the moment. I've created an expression that calculates the working days between 2 dates which works fine.

```
=(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value,
Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value))
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value,
Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value)*2)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```

The issue I have is that if the **TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE** is blank then the results of this expression is #ERROR.

I need to tweak this expression so it will basically say if the visit date is blank then display nothing but still incorporate it into my working days formula

Answer (score 0):

This is because SSRS evaluates the entire expression before it tries to find the actual path for the values it has.  Therefore it will try and find the Weekday of Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value, even if it is blank, and will therefore throw an error.

The solution to this is to handle all your potential blank or empty values from the beginning.  In this instance changing the line

```
IIF(Weekday(Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```

to

```
iif(iif(isnothing(Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value), 
        "", 
        Fields!TCY_TENANCY_VISIT_DATE.Value), 1) = 7,
    1,
    0)
```

should do the trick.  You may also need to repeat this process for your other values if there is a chance they could be null.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but it doesn't like the syntax as in the usual red underline occurs so not sure if I have to play around with the brackets.